# Nested flexbox is overflowing screen

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, chakra-ui

I'm trying to get the chart to extend to the bottom only. I tried using a column flex box with `height="100vh"`. However, it's overflowing the screen.

[image]

```
<Flex direction="column" height="100vh">
  <Flex flex="1" direction="row">
    <div>123456789010 </div>
    <Box flex="1">
      <div>| 123</div>
      <div>| 123</div>
      <div>| 123</div>
      <div>| 123</div>
      <div>| 123</div>
      <ThreeDataPoint />
    </Box>
  </Flex>
</Flex>
```

I notice that it'll work if I don't have any text above the chart. However, when I put anything above, it will cause it to overflow. It seems to be because the flexbox doesn't notice there's anything above, and is sizing the chart as if there's nothing there.

What could be occurring?

[CODESANDBOX HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/wild-dawn-cfpoz?file=/src/index.tsx)

Answer (score 1):

**Try configuring the props of your `react-financial-charts` components.**

The auto-sizing behavior of your `react-financial-charts` package seems to be causing this issue.

When inspecting the page in the browser, you’ll notice that your `.react-financial-charts` element has a hardcoded `height` equal to the height of the browser viewport. I had a look at this component with [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) in Chrome, and it seems to contain an `AutoSizer` component that may be causing this issue.

You export your `BasicLineSeries` component this way:

```js
export default withSize({ style: { minHeight: 0 } })(
  withDeviceRatio()(BasicLineSeries)
);
```

So my guess would be that `withSize` creates `AutoSizer`, which by default will resize the component to the size of the browser viewport.

The solution would then be to check the documentation for this package and figure out which props you need to use to tell it not to resize automatically.

[image]

Comment: Good investigation. This might be part of the eventual solution: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/issues/772

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to simply add `overflow="hidden"` prop to your `Flex` component like this :  `<Flex direction="column" height="100vh" overflow="hidden">`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. It just chops off the bottom of the graph. I need the graph to rescale according to the flex box (which it certainly *is* capable of doing, it does so nicely when it's rendered by itself on the page, only failing to do so in this  flexbox context).